# Maven Build task fails with "JavaScript heap out of memory"

Tags: azure, maven, azure-devops, heap-memory

I'm working over Azure Devops and I have a pipeline that builds the app with maven. Actually I'm using the Azure task to make the build.

```
  - task: Maven@3
    displayName: "Common - Build"
    inputs:
      mavenPomFile: 'web/pom.xml'
      goals: "clean install"
      options: "-Dmaven.test.skip=true -P packaging -s $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ci-maven-settings.xml -Dmaven.repo.local=$(MVN_CACHE_FOLDER)"
      publishJUnitResults: false
```

Sometimes when I run the pipe and this task start, it fails with the following error (I'm running it on a hosted agent):

```
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
[ERROR]  1: 0x8d20d0 node::Abort() [node]
[ERROR]  2: 0x8d211c  [node]
[ERROR]  3: 0xb02b6e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
[ERROR]  4: 0xb02da4 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
[ERROR]  5: 0xef02e2  [node]
[ERROR]  6: 0xef03e8 v8::internal::Heap::CheckIneffectiveMarkCompact(unsigned long, double) [node]
[ERROR]  7: 0xefc512 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
[ERROR]  8: 0xefce44 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
[ERROR]  9: 0xeffab1 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
[ERROR] 10: 0xec8fd4 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationSpace) [node]
[ERROR] 11: 0x116846e v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInNewSpace(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
[ERROR] 12: 0x222ff2edc01d 
[ERROR] error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

The weird thing here is that it happens suddenly. Sometimes works perfectly and sometimes fail. The tasks start to run, try to compile things, but in some point it fails. The unique solution that I found was restart the pipeline execution.

I also tried using the parameter "mavenOption = 'Xmx2048" the tasks fails at the begginig and I got the following error:

```
##[error]Build failed.
##[error]Exit code 1 returned from process: file name '/home/vsts/agents/2.186.1/externals/node10/bin/node', arguments '"/home/vsts/work/_tasks/Maven_ac4ee482-65da-4485-a532-7b085873e532/3.186.0/maventask.js"'.
```

Has anyone a similar issue before? I really appreciate any help on this!
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add a cmd task first to expend the size of the space.

Add this under the task:

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096
```

[image]